# PHP setDate function of DateTime setting different date

Tags: php, datetime

I am learning to use PHP DateTime class and I came across the handy 'setDate' method. I tried to do the following to compare 2 dates:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$newDate = clone $date;
$newDate->setDate(2017, 08, 29);

if($date > $newDate){
    echo 'yes';

} else{
    echo "no";
}
```

According to the current date it shall return 'no' but it returned 'yes'. so I did a `var_dump($newDate);` and it returned:

```
object(DateTime)[2]
  public 'date' => string '2016-12-29 00:31:02.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Zurich' (length=13)
```

It returned 2016-12-29 as the date which is not what I intended to set.

surely there something really wrong with what I am doing. Please help me find my mistake. Thanks

Comment: Try to use 8 instead of 08 in second parameter of setDate function

Comment: Numbers prefixed with `0` in PHP are treated as octal, so `08` is octal 8, which is an invalid octal number, so treated as 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `08`, it need to be `8` like below:-

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime();
$newDate = clone $date;
$newDate->setDate(2017, 8, 29);

if($date > $newDate){
    echo 'yes';

} else{
    echo "no";
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/839909

Why:- As @Mark Baker tell correctly:-

***Numbers prefixed with `0` in PHP are treated as `octal`, so `08` is `octal 8`, which is an invalid octal number, so treated as `0`***

And because of it you get `yes` as output:- https://eval.in/839910

You can check a number is octal or not like below:-

```
<?php

function is_octal($x) {
    return decoct(octdec($x)) == $x;
}

echo is_octal(08); // true
```

Output:- https://eval.in/839915   (the above code will work in php<7)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the clone - just instantiate the new DateTime object according to your needs.  Example: https://iconoun.com/demo/temp_sameer.php

```html
<?php // demo/temp_sameer.php
/**
 * Working with DateTime objects
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426371/php-setdate-function-of-datetime-setting-different-date
 * http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';

// NOW
$date = new DateTime();

// DIFFERENT DATE
$newDate = new DateTime('2017-08-29');

// SHOW THE OBJECTS
var_dump($date, $newDate);

// MAKE THE COMPARISONS
if($date > $newDate){
    echo 'yes';
} else{
    echo "no"; // OUTPUTS "no"
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know when you'll be keeping that URL on your site https://iconoun.com/demo/temp_sameer.php - If and when you do decide to no longer make it available or you're no longer the domain's registrant, it'll trigger a 404 and in turn your question stands to get flagged as a non-existant URL, that or edited by someone else in the future. It's usually good practice/idea to use https://eval.in/ 's website instead.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  i am agreed with you. giving URL of some personal kind of domain is not a good idea. Using a complete free online platform like `eval.in`,`fiddle.net`etc is right idea.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  The URL posted is the exact resource shown in the code snippet, so it's just a convenience thing (and it shows the author of the question that I actually tested the code).  Anyone can copy the code snippet from Stack and get the same results you would see at the URL.  I usually keep those examples around for months or years.